# error in WP Snap plugin

Tags: wordpress

this plugin is showing following error :
"Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 4"
I tried to solve it by adding \ at fourth offset, error was removed but now plugin is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

What is the full error message?  There should be a particular php file at the end of the error.

There's probably an error in your permalink structure, or if you added some type of permalink plugin.  Or you're probably getting that error because your blog has no content. It also could mean that you're using an older version of the plugin.  Again, it's difficult to say without the entire error message, and what php file is causing the problem.  But you can try changing this:

```
Code: Select all
if (preg_match("/$bad/i", strtolower($comments))){$allow = false;}
```

to this:

```
Code: Select all
if (@preg_match("/$bad/i", strtolower($comments))){$allow = false;}
```